# Synonymize [tfs] with [team-foundation-server]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

It looks like the [Team Foundation Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) tags have gotten jumbled:

- [tfs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tfs) has a tag wiki excerpt, but only three questions.
- [team-foundation-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/team-foundation-server) has 34 questions, but no wiki excerpt.

TFS is a pretty common abbreviation for Team Foundation server, so it makes sense to merge the tags and synonymize [tfs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tfs) to [team-foundation-server](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/team-foundation-server).

Comment: I left the tag wikis alone, because `tfs`'s didn't actually explain anything.